# Setting the UserProfile values

Tags: python, django

I have created my UserProfile model as [instructed in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#adding-userprofile-fields-to-the-admin) but how can I pass the values to be saved from my view. This is how my view looks like:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        now = timezone.now()
        user = User.objects.create(
            username     = form.cleaned_data['username'],
            first_name   = form.cleaned_data['username'],
            last_name    = form.cleaned_data['username'],
            email        = form.cleaned_data['email'],
            is_staff     = False,
            is_active    = False,
            is_superuser = False,
            last_login   = now,
            date_joined  = now
        )

    user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
    user.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update 1

Since, you are using post_save() signal on `User` model to create `UserProfile` object, you can access newly created profile user after calling user.save()

```
profile = user.get_profile()
profile.verified = False
profile.ip_address = get_client_ip()
profile.save()
```

---

I assume, you have `UserProfile` model in your `models.py`.

```
## Create a forms.py file inside your app and define an UserProfileForm similar to this

from django.forms import ModelForm

## using relative import because it's good practice, and I don't know what's name of your app
from .models import UserProfile

class UserProfileForm(ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ("user",)


## In views.py

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        now = timezone.now()
        user = User.objects.create(
            username     = form.cleaned_data['username'],
            first_name   = form.cleaned_data['username'],
            last_name    = form.cleaned_data['username'],
            email        = form.cleaned_data['email'],
            is_staff     = False,
            is_active    = False,
            is_superuser = False,
            last_login   = now,
            date_joined  = now
        )

    user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
    user.save()
    profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
    profile.user = user
    profile.save()
```

However, I don't understand why are you not using your `RegistrationForm` even after initializing and validating it.

Comment: The profile fields are not coming from the form, please check: http://goo.gl/jHcIL -- All I want to do is to save verified and ip_address fields.

Comment: You UserProfile object is already created due to `post_save` signal handler. You can get newly created user profile object using profile = user.get_profile().

You can save other attributes to profile after that

profile = user.get_profile()
profile.verified = False
profile.ip_address = get_client_ip()

Comment: Thank you very much. I wonder how the painfully detailed docs ignored clarifying this.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the request is a POST, all of your form data is collected and you can pass it back to the view just by passing it to a dictionary.

```
d=dict(username=form.cleaned_data["username"]), ... )
...
return render_to_resopnse("mytemplate.html", d, context_instance)
```

Comment: What I meant is how to save the additional data of UserProfile class to the database.